# How to convert array float* to float**?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, floating-point, buffer

I have a function expecting arguments like so:

```
fooReplace(float** input, float** output, int blockSize);
```

and I need to pass buffer containing two arrays of data into `fooReplace`. I can access buffer data like so:

```
float* data = buffer->getData(); // return float*;
int mBlockSize = buffer->getOffset(); //
```

but I cannot figure out how to convert it to `float**` so I can pass data into `fooReplace`.

I know this is basic C++ stuff, but I got stuck on this for days, and I cannot find any solution.

Comment: There are two practical possibilities for what the `output` formal argument expects: (1) a pointer to a pointer to array of `float`, so that this is really an output argument (the pointer to array will be updated), or (2) a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of `float`, which data it will update. One can of course answer for each practical possibility. But it would be much better if you **included the necessary information** in the question.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ > sorry, you are correct

Comment: Judging from the function's name (i.e., `fooReplace`) and by making a wild guess, I think that `float**` serves for passing your arrays by reference.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for the cast you can do

```
float* data = buffer->getData(); // return float*;
int mBlockSize = buffer->getOffset(); //
float** data_ptr = &data; // is of type float**
```

However as @Cheers and hth. - Alf points out in his comment you should try to understand why `fooReplace` wants a pointer to pointer.